# mongo count rows from an array of provided data

Tags: mongodb

I have collection like this:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("4d663451d1e7242c4b68e000"), 
  "topic" : "abc", 
  "subLevel" : {
     "id" : 1
  }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b69e000"), 
    "topic" : "bce", 
    "subLevel" : {
        "id" : 1
     }
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b70e000"), 
    "topic" : "bec", 
    "subLevel" : {
        "id" : 2
     }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d6634514cb5cb2c4b70e000"), 
    "topic" : "vvv", 
    "subLevel" : {
        "id" : 3
     }
}
```

and I need to count how many documents exist for provided subLevel.id list, for example if I provide 1 and 2 it should show me that for 1 we have 2 documents and for 2 only 1 document and simply omit document where subLevel.id is 3 as it's not in the list of id's.

I tried to do it with a aggregate

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate( [
   { $project: 
       {  "has_sublevel" : {$in: [ "subLevel.id", [1 , 2 ]]} }
   },
   { $group: { _id : "$subLevel.id", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
] )
```

but result is

```
{
   _id : null,
   count: 4
}
```

how can I do it, thanks in advance!

If transform it to SQL which I familiar more, query should look like this:

```
select subLevelId, count(id) FROM products where subLevelId in (1,2) group by subLevelId
```

Comment: `{  "has_sublevel" : {$in: [ "subLevel.id", [1 , 2 ]]} }` yields to `{has_sublevel: true}` (or false), i.e. field `subLevel.id` does not exist anymore after `$project`. Maybe replace `$project` by `$set` which will preserve existing fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understand correctly, you are so so close, check this query:

- First use `$match` to get only documents whose `subLevel.id` is 1 or 2.
- Then, as you have done, `$group` by the `id` and sum to get total count:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { "subLevel.id": { "$in": [ 1, 2 ] } }
  },
  {
    "$group": { "_id": "$subLevel.id", "count": { "$sum": 1 } }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YNOrqVeCNPq)

Answer (score 1):

You will need this:

```
db.products.aggregate([  {$match:{ "subLevel.id":{ $in:[1,2]  } }}   , {$group:{ _id:"$subLevel.id" , count:{$sum:1}   } }   ])
```

which is same like:

```
db.products.aggregate([  {$match:{ $or:[{"subLevel.id":1},{"subLevel.id":2}   ]}}   , {$group:{ _id:"$subLevel.id" , count:{$sum:1}   } }   ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the respective docs into their respective arrays and then get their sizes:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "subLevel.id": {
        $in: [
          1,
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$subLevel.id",
      ids: {
        $push: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: false,
      ids: {
        $size: "$ids"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playgroud: https://mongoplayground.net/p/J1ei37l1K5-