# check it at least one row exist for each element from an array of provided data

Tags: mongodb

this one is related to my previous question [mongo count rows from an array of provided data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585911/mongo-count-rows-from-an-array-of-provided-data) ... my real collection is to big, and it take almost 4 minutes to query and get that count with grouping, and really I need to check if there is an document for each subLevel.id or not. Not sure if it'll be faster... thought, but I want to try and I can't find a way of doing it....

How it should work is to get first value from in clause and search until it found matching document, and jump to next one if found or reach the end of collection. Again if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think it will be faster, you can create index in `subLevel.id` and set pagination using `$sort` by _id and `$skip` and `$limit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the aggregation is slow because it spends a lot of time read documents from disk, and moving those documents through the pipeline.

MongoDB can use an optimized COUNT_SCAN stage to count documents if the query can be serviced by a single scan of a contiguous range of an index.

The query from the question you mentioned was

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { "subLevel.id": { "$in": [ 1, 2 ] } }
  },
  {
    "$group": { "_id": "$subLevel.id", "count": { "$sum": 1 } }
  }
])
```

To use the optimization, the collection will need to have an index on `{"subLevel.id":1}`, and you will need to submit each id separately.  From the mongo shell this might look like:

```
[1, 2].map(v => {
   return {
           value:v, 
           count: db.collection.countDocuments({"subLevel.id":v})
          }
})
```

While this would require a separate query to the database for each id, the performance benefit of handling the query without needing to load a single document should significantly reduce the overall run time.